# How to get multiple av_read_frame with FFmpeg

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, function, ffmpeg

I want to get "2 signals" when I read an audio file. I know that I must use the FFmpeg function av_read_frame, but I have just that I call "1 signal". How can I have multiple signals to treat each signal in different way ?

My code is like that :

```
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet) >= 0)
{
    /* AVPacket == Audio */
    if (packet->stream_index == audioStream)
    {
        /* Décodage des packets */
        ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &got_picture, packet);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in decoding audio frame");
            return (-1);
        }
        if (got_picture > 0)
        {
            /* Convertissage de l'audio */
            swr_convert(au_convert_ctx, &out_buffer, MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE, (const uint8_t **)pFrame->data, pFrame->nb_samples);

#if 1

            /* Affichage des informations dans la console */
            printf("Index : %5d\t Points : %lld\t Packet size : %d\n", index, packet->pts, packet->size);

#endif /* 1 */

#if OUTPUT_PCM

            /* Fonction pour écrire dans le fichier */
            fwrite(out_buffer, 1, out_buffer_size, pFile);

#endif /* OUTPUT_PCM */

            /* Incrémentation */
            index = index + 1;
        }

#if USE_SDL

        while (audio_len > 0)
            SDL_Delay(1);
        /* Attribution des valeurs avec les variables globales */
        audio_chunk = (Uint8 *)out_buffer;
        audio_len = out_buffer_size;
        audio_pos = audio_chunk;
        SDL_PauseAudio(0);

#endif /* USE_SDL */

    }
    /* Libérer la structure AVPacket */
    av_free_packet(packet);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you have a file with two audio streams? Check AVPacket.stream_index. Note that each stream will require its own AVCodecContext.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje, Not exactly, I mean I have one file which gives one audio stream that I want to duplicate to get two audio streams.

Comment: Ah; use av_copy_packet() or av_packet_clone(), depending on whether you want to actually copy the data (copy), i.e. allowing you to modify one without affecting the other array, or just copy the reference to the data (clone), which means the data pointer is still the same (and modifying one will modify both), you now just have 2 references to it.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje, Thank you, it works. Now, I have another question about filters. I want to apply the bass filter and the treble filter. How can I do with packets (If filters can be used with packets or other) ?

Comment: You need to decode the compressed data to get an AVFrame. Then, the AVFrame can be input in a filter chain, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38103053/4726410 for a related example.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje, Thank you for the help. I have some questions about the FFmpeg library. Do you think that I can add you on Skype (microzion) to discuss on my project ?

Comment: I prefer email over skype. Any reason you can't use the public mailinglist?

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje, I just prefer email that's more simple. At which email may I join you ?

Comment: rsbultje@gmail.com works